Is my password safe in a pyinstaller .exe?
So I built a program to run reports. I put credentials in the python script. I want to distribute this to user without python so I converted it to a .exe using pyinstaller. I wasn't able to find the credential by looking at the .exe in notepad, since it doesn't appear human readable. However, I wanted to ask, can the credentials be discovered?

Yes, they can be discovered, probably without very much difficulty.

How? I'm interested. Also, would there be any way to hide it within the executable?

It's an elementary reverse-engineering question.

then offer some source or help with how I can perform this elementary activity? I'd even be willing to offer the file to see if you can pull a username and password from it.

pyinstaller is open-source but I've not looked at and I'm not going to. Let an expert explain how.

When you run an .exe created with Pyinstaller, it will create a temporary folder containing the required libraries, any files you may have copied, and a compiled version of your source code in .pyc files.
These files can be decompiled, even if not that easily, so your credentials can in principle be accessed by an attacker.
Read more about it here and here.

Thanks for the information. Looks like I could compile to Cython if I want to hide it further, but in theory it could still be discovered. Seems like it's a good amount of effort to see my username and password though and the account I'm using is specifically design to just run reports plus it's just given to people I know (they could share it). I guess I could always just remove it and ask the user to input a username and password. Really appreciate the information though.

Looking at it further it does looks like it may be pretty easy. The uncompiler looks like it doesn't uncompile the current version of python, but I'm guessing at some point it will support the version I'm creating my programs in.
